# Using GraphServiceClient to retrieve group info of Azure Ad members

Tags: asp.net, authentication, graph, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

i want to retrieve all members of a Azure Ad group within my backend application. I followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example) and here is my code:
[image]

> But I always get this error when using the method: 
>   Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException Message: An
>   error occurred sending the request.
>
> ---> Microsoft.Graph.Auth.AuthenticationException: Code:
>   authenticationChallengeRequired Message: Authentication challange is
>   required.

Can someone help me with that? I didn't find this specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you register an app registration in azure ad, create a secret, set the proper api permissions? 
there are even quickstarts in the app registration portal that helps you configure the code and give you a pre set up project that you can experiment with.

Also your code seems to be missing scopes, you need to request the appropriate scopes for graph api token to access groups.

I think the documentation here is better: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth

and if you check the unit tests here for authorization code flow: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Auth.Test/ConfidentialClient/AuthorizationCodeProviderTests.cs

gives you a good example of how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The problem was that I used the AuthorizationCodeProvider which acquires a token in the name of the user, but in my situation I need to use the ClientCredentialProvider to access the graph without a user. Then I needed the permission to read groups and members also when no user is authenticated and it works over the secret.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously these parameters(clientId/tenantId/clientSecret/groupId) need to be replaced with specific strings.

You could find `clientId` and `tenantId` via **App registrations-> Overview:**

[image]

`clientSecret` via **App registrations-> Certificates & secrets:**

[image]

`groupId` via **Azure Active Directory -> Groups:**

[image]

---

You could also store the specific strings in a profile and read the strings in the file.
And the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp) will help you to understand it.

**AccountController.cs :**

```
IConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient;
                daemonClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Startup.clientId)
                    .WithAuthority(string.Format(AuthorityFormat, tenantId))
                    .WithRedirectUri(Startup.redirectUri)
                    .WithClientSecret(Startup.clientSecret)
                    .Build();
```

**Web.config :**

```
  <add key="ida:ClientId" value="[Enter your client ID]" />
  <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="[Enter your client secret]" />
```

**Startup.Auth.cs :**

```
public static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
public static string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
public static string redirectUri = "https://localhost:44316/";
```